# Is Demand paging implemented in Android?

Tags: android, memory-management, paging

Suppose I have an executable of size 60MB and I want to execute it on android(ARM), will 60MB be allocated to load the code onto the RAM?

I remember studying about demand paging in Linux kernel. Is it relevant here? If yes, is it implemented in Linux kernels used in Android?